# make background image to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gallery

i am using this [**jquery iviewer**](http://test.dpetroff.ru/jquery.iviewer/test/)

i want to link these image thumble to another link.

can i use image map for this or any other way to make image thumble to link. these are really add with full image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add this in between your script tag:

```
var objects = [{x: 0, y: 800, r: 800, isInObject: isInCircle, title: 'whole image', getCenter: getRectCenter }]
```

**note**: set y and r to cover your image.

And this when you set defaults for iviewer:

```
onClick: function(coords) {
var object = whereIam(coords.x, coords.y);                       
if (object) 
window.location="cart.html";
}
```

**whereIam** is a default function available with iviewer.